# How to debug a ConfuserEx assembly?

Tags: c#, wpf, confuserex

I'm using `ConfuserEx` for obfuscate my application, what I did is:

1. Drag and drop the exe on the ConfuserEx software
2. Set the rule as maximum protection (also tried the lowest protection)
3. Clicked the "Protect".

When I press on the generated exe this simply not run, if instead I doesn't apply the rule of the step 2, the exe will run, how can I debug this? I doesn't get any error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, Confuser is an open source project. So download the source code, compile and debug it.
Obfuscate a WPF-Project is a bit tricky, since WPF based on reflection and reflection isn't "friendly" to obfuscating.
You can try to customize maximum preset and remove such options as

- Resource obfuscating
- Rename

So it can work. Don't forget the dlls(if you have any).

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how can I remove from the obfuscation the option you suggested?

Comment: Tab:Settings->Click on project-> on the right side button for editing the rule

Comment: I did this but not seems to working, any other solution?

Comment: Remove consequently other options to see which option makes the problem.

Comment: Do you have any dlls, they should be also obfuscated?

Comment: ok I fixed, thank you I just add "remove" to reference, now all working well. you saved my day thanks!!!!!